# How can i change background : linear gradient to tailwind linear gradient

Tags: css, background, tailwind-css, linear-gradients

I have this background in simple css:

```
 background: linear-gradient(152deg,#fff,#00bfd8 42%,#0083f5);
```

I want to add it into the tailwind css:

```
  <section class="relative bg-[here] table w-full py-36 lg:py-44">
```

Comment: It should be somthing like this: <section class="bg-gradient-to-r from-white-500 via-cyan-500 to-blue-500">

Comment: @amel  It is not working

Answer (score 5):

For equal color stops use tailwind's bg-gradient-to class

`bg-gradient-to-br from-white via-[#00bfd8] to-[#0083f5]`

If you want to use your custom colour stops use arbitrary values

`bg-[linear-gradient(152deg,_#fff,_#00bfd8_42%,_#0083f5)]`

Use "_" underscore for spaces : [ref](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#handling-whitespace)

To use tailwind colors in custom gradients: replace hex code with **theme(colors.blue.500)**
[Theme()](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme)

Check it out in this [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cgOkxUpmMl)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
className="h-[1300px] 
    bg-contain bg-center bg-no-repeat
    bg-[url('/images/xxx/pos-banner-bg-mobile.webp'),linear-gradient(0deg,_#000000_4%,_#000000_22%)]
    sm:bg-cover 
    sm:bg-[url('/images/xxx/pos-banner-bg-desktop.webp'),linear-gradient(0deg,_#000000_4%,_#000000_22%)]
"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have `background: linear-gradient(180deg, #0f1026 0.29%, #1b2040 100%);`

then in tailwind css it can be written as
`bg-[linear-gradient(180deg,_#0f1026_29%,_#1b2040_100%)]`

*Note: Make sure to give no space in above classname*